# How to redefine Opt+Left Arrow and Opt+Right Arrow hotkeys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I would like to use <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> as hotkeys in some apps but when I try to use them, they still behave as beginning and end of line. How do I unset the OS's bindings for these key combos?

I would like to do this without using Karabiner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `${HOME}/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` doesn't exist, create it as:

```
{
}
```

Add the following to `${HOME}/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` between the braces:

```
    "~\UF702"  = "noop:"; /* OPT+LEFT_ARROW: NOOP */
    "~\UF703"  = "noop:"; /* OPT+RIGHT_ARROW: NOOP */
```

For more info about the syntax see the article [Mac OS X Keybinding Key Syntax](http://xahlee.info/kbd/osx_keybinding_key_syntax.html).